# Why can't sbt/assembly find the main classes in a project with multiple subprojects?

Tags: scala, sbt, project-structure

We're combining two of our Scala projects because they share a lot of functionality. I'm setting up the new repo, and have the following `build.sbt`:

```scala
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.10"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.2.15" % Test

lazy val project1 = (project in file("project1"))
  .dependsOn(core)
  .settings(
    name := "Project 1",
    assembly / mainClass := Some("project1.Main"),
    assembly / assemblyJarName := "project1.jar",
  )

lazy val project2 = (project in file("project2"))
  .dependsOn(core)
  .settings(
    name := "Project 2",
    assembly / mainClass := Some("project2.Main"),
    assembly / assemblyJarName := "project2.jar",
  )

lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
  .settings(
    name := "Core",
  )
```

Basically, Project 1 and Project 2 should both depend on Core, but not on each other.

My `src` directory looks like this:

```
src
  main/scala
    core
      Core.scala
    project1
      Main.scala
    project2
      Main.scala
  test/scala
    core
      TestCore.scala
    project1
      TestProject1.scala
    project2
      TestProject2.scala
```

For the moment, `Core.scala` is:

```scala
package core

object Core {
    def hello() = {
        println("hello from core!")
    }
}
```

`project1/Main.scala` is:

```scala
package project1

import core.Core

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        hello()
        Core.hello()
    }

    def hello() = { println("hello from project 1!") }
}
```

and similarly, `project2/Main.scala` is:

```scala
package project2

import core.Core

object Main {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        hello()
        Core.hello()
    }

    def hello() = { println("hello from project 2!") }
}
```

I can run both of these main classes in the sbt terminal from the project root, either by entering `run` and selecting the main class I'd like to use, or entering `runMain <main_class>` (the two main classes are `project1.Main` and `project2.Main`). However, if I switch to one of the subprojects (for example, by entering `project project1`) and then enter `run`, sbt is no longer able to detect a main class. Additionally, if I compile the project using `assembly`, I can't run either `project1.jar` or `project2.jar` because they can't find their main classes either. Why exactly is this happening?

Furthermore, I noticed that I can still import `project2` into Project 1 and `project1` into Project 2, even though I've only set `dependsOn` for `core`. Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing completely different notions, subprojects and packages.

If you want to have subprojects

```
lazy val project1 = (project in file("project1"))

lazy val project2 = (project in file("project2"))

lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
```

then the project structure should be completely different

```
core
  src
    main/scala
      Core.scala
    test/scala
      TestCore.scala
project1
  src
    main/scala
      Main.scala
    test/scala
      TestProject1.scala
project2
  src
    main/scala
      Main.scala
    test/scala
      TestProject2.scala
```

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Directories.html

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Multi-Project.html

If you put

```
package core

object Core
```

```
package project1

object Main
```

```
package project2

object Main
```

to the same directory `src/main/scala` then `core`, `project1`, `project2` are packages, not subprojects and you have the only project.

Surely you can have both subprojects and packages. Then the project structure can be

```
core                    <-- this is a subproject
  src
    main/scala
      core              <-- this is a package
        Core.scala
    test/scala
      core
        TestCore.scala
project1
  src
    main/scala
      project1
        Main.scala
    test/scala
      project1
        TestProject1.scala
project2
  src
    main/scala
      project2
        Main.scala
    test/scala
      project2
        TestProject2.scala
```

but generally there is no connection between subproject names and package names.

In principle you can modify the project structure so that it will differ from default

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html

> if I switch to one of the subprojects (for example, by entering `project project1`) and then enter `run`, sbt is no longer able to detect a main class

That's because now your subprojects `project1`, `project2`, `core` (declared in `build.sbt`) are empty. You put everything to the single directory `src/main/scala` that belongs to

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
```

which is created implicitly by default if you don't create it manually.

[Maven: difference module - java package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42561194/maven-difference-module-java-package)

[Is a Maven project necessarily a Java package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48427844/is-a-maven-project-necessarily-a-java-package)

[Whats the difference between package and groupId in maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59206147/whats-the-difference-between-package-and-groupid-in-maven)

Comment: this worked! yea I'm new to scala and haven't worked in the java world in nearly a decade, so I think I was getting terminology mixed up